# Type of unsigned bit-fields: int or unsigned int

Tags: c, c99, bit-fields

Section 6.3.1.1 of the C99 standard contains:

> The following may be used in an
>   expression wherever an `int` or
>   `unsigned int` may  be used:
>
> [...] A bit-field of type `_Bool`,
>   `int`, `signed int`, or `unsigned
>   int`.
>
> If an `int` can represent all values
>   of the original type, the value is
>   converted to an `int`;  otherwise, it
>   is converted to an `unsigned int`.

It seems to me that this implies that `unsigned int` bit-fields are promoted to `int`, except when the width of the unsigned bit-field is equal to the width of `int`, in which case the last phrase applies.

I have the following program:

```
struct S { unsigned f:32; } x = { 28349};

unsigned short us = 0xDC23L;

main(){
  int r = (x.f ^ ((short)-87)) >= us;
  printf("%d\n", r);
  return r;
}
```

And two systems to execute this program (`int` is 32-bit on both systems). One system says this program prints 1, and the other says that it prints 0. My question is, against which of the two systems should I file a bug report? (I am leaning towards filing the report against the system that prints 0, because of the excerpt above)

Comment: What is the value of `(x.f ^ ((short)-87))` on your two systems?  Also, what is `sizeof(short)`?

Comment: @Oli On both systems, `-28396` if printed with %d and `4294938900` if printed with %u. I think it's really more the question of which type the expression should be considered to have. `sizeof(short)` is 2, and `char`s have 8 bits.

Comment: Hm, it says `represent all values of the original *type*` I am not so sure of what the outcome should be. "Bitfielded" integer types are definitively not types of their own, so type in there could only refer to the types that you are giving in the second sentence. But then `unsigned` would always be unsigned. My understanding would be that there is first a implicit cast of the field to the original type, and then promotion rules apply.

Comment: @Jens I completely agree: for me, "bit-field of width 31" is not a type. But I can't help noticing that all compilers I try (clang 1.5 and gcc 4.2.1 right now) make the program return 0 if you change the `32` to `31`, indicating that they promote `x.f` to `int` and do a signed `>=` comparison.

Comment: I found two compilers that still return 1 in that case: `pcc` and `tcc`. `gcc` 4.4, `clang` 2.9, `icc` 12.0 and opencc 4.2.4 behave as you describe. But since the later all mimic gcc, this probably doesn't say much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that this ambiguity has already been detected by the standards committee since the current draft clarifies that sentence:

> If an int can represent all values of
>   the original type (as restricted by
>   the width, for a bit-field), the value
>   is converted to an int;

Comment: Unfortunately, 6.7.2 says *...for  bit-fields, it is implementation-defined whether the specifier `int` designates the same type as `signed int` or the same type as `unsigned int`*. So what is the "original type" of an `int` bitfield? Is it the apparent one, `int`, or the implementation-defined substitute? If an `int` is 16 bits wide, and we make an `int field : 16`, if the value is 0-65535, one would think that it must convert to `unsigned int`; if it is `-32768` to `32767`, or `-32767` to `32767`, it must convert to `int`.  The wording hardly makes it clear.

Comment: It's unclear also whether the sentence means that if all the values of a bitfield fit into `int`, it must go to `int`. e.g. `unsigned field : 3`. Here, all values of the original `unsigned int` type don't fit into `int`, but "restricted by width" they do (the values 0 to 7). But in that case, the "original type" is neither here nor there. If the intent is simply "if the values of the bit-field fit into `int`, then it converts to `int`, otherwise `unsigned int`", why didn't they just write that?

Answer (score 1):

My reading is the same as you: an unsigned bitfield of the size of an int should have unsigned int as type, smaller than an int it should have signed int type.

The compilers I've access (gcc on x86, Sun CC on Sparc, IBM xlC on POWER) have a behavior matching this reading (printing 1 in your program, printing 0 if the bitfield is reduced to 31 bits or made signed).