# Comparison of a bitfield vs a (negative) integer, undefined behavior or compiler bugs?

Tags: c

Here is a small program. Should this print 0 or 1, or does it have undefined behavior ?

```
#include <stdio.h>
struct S0 {
  unsigned f1 : 1;
};

struct S0 s;

int main (void) {
  int x = -3;
  int y = x >= (0, s.f1);
  printf ("%d\n", y);
  return 0;
}
```

This is taken from a resent [CSmith](http://embed.cs.utah.edu/csmith/) test, and this case is discussed more [here](http://blog.regehr.org/archives/558) .

In particular, GCC, KCC, and CompCert outputs 0, while MSVC 2010, ICC 12.0.2 and recent Clang outputs 1.

Comment: The discrepancy really goes to show how problematic bit-fields are.  It is simplest to avoid them.

Comment: All compilers compiling it as C, not C++? Because C++ has subtle differences here, IIRC.

Answer (score 12):

Interesting question.

According to the C99 draft standard 6.5.17.1, the type of `(0, s.f1)` is the same as that of `s.f1`, which (per 6.7.2.1.9) is "an unsigned integer type consisting of 1 bit". This is an arithmetic type by virtue of being an integer type, its precision is 1 (per 6.2.6.2.6, and 6.2.6.1.3 implies no padding bits), and therefore its rank is less than that of `int` (per the second item under 6.3.1.1.1; int has a precision of at least 15, since it must be able to represent values in the range -32767 to 32767 (see 5.2.4.2.1)).

Since both `x` and the expression `(0, s.f1)` have arithmetic type, the usual arithmetic conversions are performed (per 6.5.8.3). Since an int can represent the full range of values of `s.f1`, it is promoted to a (signed) int (per 6.3.1.1.2). Then since both operands are (signed) ints, the common real type is signed int (per 6.3.1.8) and therefore the result of the comparison should be 0.

Answer (score 5):

AFAIK, the type of `s.f1` is `unsigned int`.  I believe the comma operator is a red herring; that comparison is equivalent to `int y = x >= s.f1;`.  Applying the "usual arithmetic conversions" (C99 6.3.1.8), the `x` is converted to `unsigned int` when doing the comparison; this conversion is well-defined (it will result in `UINT_MAX-2`.  Hence it will be greater.  So the answer should be `1`.

Comment: Question is if the "usual aritmetic conversions" apply, see e.g. the comment on the blog post [here](http://blog.regehr.org/archives/558#comment-2698)

Comment: GCC, ICC and CLANG give 0 (and no more warning) on my machine if you remove the comma operator.

Comment: @Lyke: Hmmm.  IMO, the type of your bit-field is simply `unsigned int` (not `unsigned int:1` or anything like that).  So according to 6.1.1.1/2, that would be promoted to `unsigned int`.

Comment: [type of unsigned bit field](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5977456/type-of-unsigned-bit-fields-int-or-unsigned-int) seems to indicate that `s.f1` should be promoted to `int`, not `unsigned int`.

Comment: it is interesting how there are two reasonable (at least for ignorant like me about what std states) answers that reasonably give 2 different results, and how there are two sets of compilers that agree each with one answer...

Answer (score 0):

I'll add this here, it's comment #39 from Rajan Bhakta, [here](http://blog.regehr.org/archives/558),

> This is an ambiguity in the standard that has been cleared up in the
>   upcoming latest revision of the ISO C Standard (commonly known as C1X
>   until it gets ratified) in section 6.3.1.1 paragraph 2. In essence the
>   bitfield type (from the result of the comma expression) is converted
>   to an int, and hence the comparison is a signed int comparison. In
>   essence, the C1X standard says that the value of y is 0.

I'd be grateful if anyone can confirm this.

Comment: It seems that the mentioned change was to add "(as restricted by the width, for a bit-field)" to the mentioned paragraph. I'm not sure that really *changes* anything for this question though, as for those who consider `(0,s.f1)` to be a bit-field the second bullet point just above that paragraph already made it clear while for those who consider the expression to somehow not be a bitfield the added text doesn't apply.