# disadvantages of using bitfields in memory

Tags: c, linux, gcc

I am in a memory constrained x64 system and I need to hold a lot of data in memory. What are the disadvantages of using this kind of data structure.

```
struct entity
{
  unsigned int hash : 26;
  unsigned int timestamp : 14; 
} __attribute__ ((__packed__));
```

I know that using bit fields is discouraged, but what are the worst drawbacks in using this non aligned data structure.

The structure will be used in memory storage and some performance degradation is expected.

Comment: How much data is required to be in memory? Does it need to be in memory at the same time?

Comment: I wouldn't say 'discouraged' - bit fields are a tool the language provides and you use them whenever they are the best choice to meet your design constraints.

Comment: If you are on a memory constrained x64 system, why not run x86 code? Your pointers will all be half the size.

Comment: Memory constrained x64 means ironically, that I have a lot more memory than x86 can address, but still not enough.

Comment: Why not just use bit masks/shifting? Not a perfect solution, but might address a couple of the disadvantages mentioned below.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Disadvantages (non-exhaustive list):

- Not portable (in the sense that the C standard places few constraints on how bitfields should be packed)
- Potential performance impact compared to "native" types (compiler has to do bit-slicing/mis-aligned accesses)
- Can't take address of individual members
- Can't apply `sizeof` to individual members
- Confusing semantics when it comes to integer promotions, etc. (see e.g. [Type of unsigned bit-fields: int or unsigned int](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5977456/type-of-unsigned-bit-fields-int-or-unsigned-int) or [Comparison of a bitfield vs a (negative) integer, undefined behavior or compiler bugs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6695193/comparison-of-a-bitfield-vs-a-negative-integer-undefined-behavior-or-compiler))

Comment: @Nik: the LSB/MSB ordering of packing in the parent word is compiler dependent.

Comment: @BlankXavier: That's only a problem if you're transferring raw data between two systems that were build with compilers that arranged the bits in different ways.

Comment: @Skizz: But if the aim here is to restrict the size of the structure to 40-bit, then there's no portable way of enforcing it.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth: Well, the given structure is 40bits and what the compiler does with it is up to the compiler - will it be 5 bytes in memory or 8 bytes. Also, the OP didn't say it had to be portable.

Comment: @Skizz: Ah, "32" was a typo.  But he also didn't say that it didn't have to be portable...

Comment: @BlankXavier: That may be true. I suppose having a list of bit-field issues would help the OP know which ones will be relevant (sizeof and address of may not be an issue for all we know).