# enums are signed

Tags: c++, enums

the following code:

```
void f3()
{
    enum AeF3
    {
        f3E1 = 1,
        f3E2,
        f3E3,
    };
    struct AsF3
    {
        AeF3 e1:2, e2:2, e3:2;
    };
    AsF3 inst;
    inst.e1 = f3E1;
    inst.e2 = f3E2;
    inst.e3 = f3E3;
    cout << "inst.e1 is " << ((inst.e1 == f3E1) ? "" : "not ") << "equal to f3E1" << endl;
    cout << "inst.e2 is " << ((inst.e2 == f3E2) ? "" : "not ") << "equal to f3E2" << endl;
    cout << "inst.e3 is " << ((inst.e3 == f3E3) ? "" : "not ") << "equal to f3E3" << endl;
}
```

generates the following output:

```
inst.e1 is equal to f3E1
inst.e2 is not equal to f3E2
inst.e3 is not equal to f3E3
```

how can i fix this error with no cast?

### more description

e2 & e3 can't hold values larger than 1, because they have to save one bit for their sign. i need a way to tell compiler not to use this bit for sign and use it still for the value instead.
i tried:

```
enum AeF3 : byte
```

but it doesn't help. instead of -2, 254 is compared, while 2 is not equal to -2 nor 254.

Comment: why do you have these numeric prefixes in many of your questions? are these Stardates for your Programmer's Log?

Comment: @rhalbersma Looks like a telephone number. BTW where is the cast?

Comment: @BЈовић They are different for different questions.

Comment: Are you really that tight on memory that you need such convolutions?  If not, forget the bit designations.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Type of unsigned bit-fields: int or unsigned int](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5977456/type-of-unsigned-bit-fields-int-or-unsigned-int)

Comment: @Steve: although programming is my work, it's a fun for me. i used to be accurate in what happens inside. i used to persist in my methods and avoid workarounds or trying other ways before i know why they happen.

Comment: @others: sounds complaining! i've described it b4. it's unuseful for others. it's just for me to know in what date i've posted. it's just a tag. StackOverflow always omits and i always persist! :D

Comment: The date you posted?  The date posted is in the author tag.

Comment: i'm not familiar with Gregorian dates

Answer (score 2):

The whole approach is wrong. The type of the enumeration in C++03 (and with that syntax in C++11) is unspecified, and creating a bitfield with an underlying enumeration type (or a signed type in general) is not the correct approach. You should probably do:

```
struct AsF3 {
   unsigned int e1 : 2;
   unsigned int e2 : 2;
   unsigned int e3 : 2;
};
```

Note that the type on the bitfield is the underlying storage type, not the type of each one of the stored elements, whether you use `AeF3` or `unsigned int`, all of the members `e1`, `e2`, `e3` will be of integral type (and not enumerations)

Comment: i used type AeF3 instead of byte or unsigned int for e1, e2 and e3 because i wanted compiler to check assignments. i wanted to avoid assigning simple values to them and i wanted all assignments be made only when right-hand of the assignment be a member of the enumeration.

Comment: i think compiler had not made the .exe file. when i use ": byte" for the enum the output changed all to "equal"!
why?! 254 is not equal to 2!

Comment: @hamidi: Uhm... I did not know that the compiler would check the type to be an enum. You learn something new every day! `byte` is not a standard type, so you would have to provide the actual type. I have tried the above code with `unsigned char` as underlying type in g++ 4.5 and works as expected. The value stored and the value retrieved are exactly the same. What compiler/version are you using? (BTW, the 254 looks like the 2bit bitset is considered as signed 2 bit integer promoted to 8bit --sign extended-- and then converted to an unsigned type; 254 is `(unsigned char)-2`)

Comment: i'm using VS 2010. when i debug the code, i get value f3E1 for inst.e1 and value 254 for inst.e2, while f3E1 is equal to 1 and f3E2 is equal to 2, not 254. as u said, the sign for inst.e2 is extended with 1 (negative) and is extended for f3E2 f3E2 with 0 (positive). so it seems that e2 is still treated as NEGATIVE. this is my question: why? and how can i tell compiler to treat e2 as positive. it seems that the MSB for a bitfield is always treated as SIGN, even if it's defined as an unsigned value.

Comment: i added the following code:
cout << "inst.e1: " << (int) inst.e1 << "\tf3E1: " << (int) f3E1 << endl;
cout << "inst.e2: " << (int) inst.e2 << "\tf3E2: " << (int) f3E2 << endl;
cout << "inst.e3: " << (int) inst.e3 << "\tf3E3: " << (int) f3E3 << endl;
and got the following output:
inst.e1: 1      f3E1: 1
inst.e2: 2      f3E2: 2
inst.e3: 3      f3E3: 3
it seems that everything is ok and it's the debugger fault that can't evaluate e2 and e3 correctly.