# sign extension in C

Tags: c, bit

I'm looking here to understand sign extension:
http://www.shrubbery.net/solaris9ab/SUNWdev/SOL64TRANS/p8.html

```c
    struct foo {
        unsigned int    base:19, rehash:13;  
    };

    main(int argc, char *argv[]) 
    {
        struct foo  a;
        unsigned long addr;

        a.base = 0x40000;
        addr = a.base << 13;        /* Sign extension here! */
        printf("addr 0x%lx\n", addr);

        addr = (unsigned int)(a.base << 13);  /* No sign extension here! */
        printf("addr 0x%lx\n", addr);
    }
```

They claim this:

------------------ 64 bit:

```
% cc -o test64 -xarch=v9 test.c
% ./test64
addr 0xffffffff80000000
addr 0x80000000
%
```

------------------ 32 bit:

```
% cc -o test32 test.c
% ./test32
addr 0x80000000
addr 0x80000000
%
```

I have 3 questions:

1. What is sign extension ? Yes I read wiki, but didn't understand when type promotion occurs, what's going on with sign extension?
2. Why ffff.. in 64 bit(referring addr) ?
3. When I do type cast, why no sign extension?

EDIT:
4. Why not an issue in 32 bit system?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
a.base << 13
```

The bitwise operator performs integer promotions on both its operands.

So this is equivalent to:

```
    (int) a.base << 13
```

which is a negative value of type `int`.

Then:

```
addr = (int) a.base << 13;
```

converts this signed negative value (`(int) a.base << 13`) to the type of `addr` which is `unsigned long` through integer conversions.

Integer conversions (C99, 6.3.1.3p2) rules that is the same as doing:

```
addr = (long) ((int) a.base << 13);
```

The conversion `long` performs the sign extension here because `((int) a.base << 13)` is a negative signed number.

On the other case, with a cast you have something equivalent to:

```
addr = (unsigned long) (unsigned int) ((int) a.base << 13);
```

so no sign extension is performed in your second case because `(unsigned int) ((int) a.base << 13)` is an unsigned (and positive of course) value.

**EDIT**: as [KerrekSB](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19260231/1119701) mentioned in his answer `a.base << 13` is actually not representable in an `int` (I assume 32-bit `int`) so this expression invokes undefined behavior and the implementation has he right to behave in any other way, for example crashing.

For information, this is definitely not portable but if you are using `gcc`, `gcc` does not consider `a.base << 13` here as undefined behavior. From `gcc` documentation:

> "GCC does not use the latitude given in C99 only to treat certain aspects of signed '<<' as undefined, but this is subject to change."

in http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Integers-implementation.html

Comment: "The bitwise operator performs integer promotions on both its operands." That's not exactly true in general - see http://codepad.org/4GVmeWXV for C++ example - the promotion is only because the RHS expression have type int.

Comment: @MaciejPiechotka this is true in C for bitwise shift operators, see *(c99, 6.5.7p3) "The integer promotions are performed on each of the operands"*

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc Because of some odd details around bit-fields, the LHS isn't an unsigned int. It's an unsigned type smaller than an int, so it gets promoted to int.

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc see *"Q1: How does an unsigned plain bitfield promote?"*  http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/dr.htm

Answer (score 3):

The left operand of the `<<` operator undergoes standard promotions, so in your case it is promoted to `int` -- so far so good. Next, the `int` of value `0x4000` is multiplied by 2<sup>13</sup>, which causes overflow and thus undefined behaviour. However, we can see what's happening: the value of the expression is now simply `INT_MIN`, the smallest representable `int`. Finally, when you convert that to an unsigned 64-bit integer, the usual modular arithmetic rules entail that the resulting value is `0xffffffff80000000`. Similarly, converting to an unsigned 32-bit integer gives the value `0x80000000`.

To perform the operation on unsigned values, you need to control the conversions with a cast:

```
(unsigned int)(a.base) << 13
```

Comment: This is not undefined behavior, the left operand of `<<` is first promoted to `int`.

Comment: @ouah: It's signed overflow. `int` is 32 bit in this situation.

Comment: oops, sorry you are right `a.base << 13` is not representable in an `int` => undefined behavior.

Comment: @ouah: IF there weren't overflow, none of this would be happening :-)

Comment: @KerrekSB Actually I can't see what's happening. When right side of = becomes INT_MIN? And you lost me on usual modular arithmetic.Where's that INT_MIN in 64 bit result?

Comment: @zubergu: No no, we're *always* an `int` at that point. But the overflow (namely computing 2^19 times 2^13) causes, on your implementationm, a representation that *corresponds* to that of `INT_MIN` (namely `1<<31`). Only after that does that negative value get converted to `unsigned long`. That last conversion is well-defined.

Comment: @KerrekSB why are we multiplying 0x4000 with 2^13? I dont understand!

Comment: @codemuncher because number<<13 is equivalent to multiplying number*(2^13). (n<<1)==n*2, (n<<2)==(n*4) and so on. Other side works too:(n>>1)==(n/2), (n>>2)==(n/4) and so on.

Comment: @zubergu ok, 0x4000 left shift 13 time is: 0x80000000, which is: 1000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000. How come wrong with 64 bit system, and not with 32 bit system. In 32 bit system, my MSB is 1, that is sign bit is 1, so isn't the number is negative? Sorry but my head is spinning!

Comment: It's fine at this point. It's signed int to unsigned long conversion that breaks. When converted leading 1 is being added 32 times at the beginning of 100000... to fit in 64 bits. On 32 bits that conversion is unnecessary so it stays 10000, not 11111111111111()0000000.

Comment: @codemuncher Look at this link, it's my question about integers conversion inspired by your question. I think I made it pretty clear how conversion goes. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19273658/integer-conversionsnarrowing-widening-undefined-behaviour  but until it's reviewed with someone better than me treat it like unconfirmed source of knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

This is more of a question about bit-fields. Note that if you change the struct to

```
struct foo {
    unsigned int    base, rehash;  
};
```

you get very different results.

As @JensGustedt noted in [Type of unsigned bit-fields: int or unsigned int](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5977456/type-of-unsigned-bit-fields-int-or-unsigned-int) the specification says:

> If an int can represent all values of the original type (as restricted by the width, for a bit-field), the value is converted to an int;

Even though you've specified that base is unsigned, the compiler converts it to a `signed int` when you read it. That's why you don't get sign extension when you cast it to `unsigned int`.

Sign extension has to do with how negative numbers are represented in binary. The most common scheme is 2s complement. In this scheme, -1 is represented in 32 bits as 0xFFFFFFFF, -2 is 0xFFFFFFFE, etc. So what should be done when we want to convert a 32-bit number to a 64-bit number, for example? If we convert 0xFFFFFFFF to 0x00000000FFFFFFFF, the numbers will have the same unsigned value (about 4 billion), but different signed values (-1 vs. 4 billion). On the other hand, if we convert 0xFFFFFFFF to 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF, the numbers will have the same signed value (-1) but different unsigned values. The former is called zero-extension (and is appropriate for unsigned numbers) and the latter is called sign-extension (and is appropriate for signed numbers). It's called "sign-extension" because the "sign bit" (the most significant, or left-most bit) is extended, or copied, to make the number wider.

Answer (score 0):

It took me a while and a lot of reading/testing.
Maybe my, beginner way to understand what's going on will get to you (as I got it)

1. a.base=0x40000 (1(0)x18) -> 19-bit bitfield
2. addr=a.base<<13.

   - any value a.base can hold int can hold, too so conversion from 19-bit unsigned int bitfield to 32-bit signed integer. (a.base is now (0)x13,1,(0)x18).
   - now (converted to signed int a.base)<<13 which results in 1(0)x31). Remember it's signed int now.
   - addr=(1(0)x31). addr is of `unsigned long` type(64 bit) so to do the assignment righ value is converted to long int. Conversion from signed int to long int make addr (1)x33,(0)x31.

And that's what being printed after all of thos converstions you weren't even aware of:
`0xffffffff80000000`.
Why the second line prints `0x80000000` is because of that cast to (unsigned int) **before** conversion to `long int`. When converting `unsigned int` to `long int` there is no bit sign so value is just filled with trailing 0's to match the size and that's all.

What's different on with 32-bit, is during conversion from `32-bit signed int` to `32-bit unsigned long` their sizes match and do trailing bit signs are added,so:
`1(0)x31` will stay `1(0)x31` 
even after conversion from int to long int(they have the same size, the value is interpreted different but bits are intact.)

Quotation from your link:

> Any code that makes this assumption must be changed to work for both
>   ILP32 and LP64. While an int and a long are both 32-bits in the ILP32
>   data model, in the LP64 data model, a long is 64-bits.

Comment: what is this:. (a.base is now (0)x13,1,(0)x18).? do you mean 0 , 13 times?

Comment: @codemuncher That's just shortcut for binary writing 13 zeros and single 1 and 18 zeros following.(000000..100000...).