# Integer conversions(narrowing, widening), undefined behaviour

Tags: c, integer, type-conversion, implicit-conversion

It was pretty difficult for me to find information on this subject in manner that I could easily understand, so I'm asking for a review of what I have found.It's all about conversion and conversion only.

---

In examples I will be referring to:

```
(signed/unsigned) int bigger;
(signed/unsigned) char smaller;
```

1. **Truncating** integers. (bigger->smaller)

   - first **truncate** `bigger` on **MSB** side to match `smaller` size.
   - second, **convert** truncated result to **signed/unsigned** depending on smaller type.

   If bigger value is too big to fit in smaller type, it results in undefined behaviour (correct me on that). However my rule should be working on all machines (correct me on that, too) and results should be predictable.
2. **Widening** integers (smaller->bigger)

   a) `signed char` -> `signed int`

   - prepend smaller with MSB (1 or 0) to match bigger size
   - convert to signed

   b) `signed char` -> `unsigned int`

   - prepend smaller with MSB (1 or 0) to match bigger size.
   - convert to unsigned

   c) `unsigned char` -> `signed int`

   - prepend with 0's to match bigger size
   - convert to signed

   d) `unsigned char` -> `unsigned int`

   - prepend with 0's to match bigger size
   - convert to unsigned

Where are undefined/unspecified behaviours that I didn' mention that could pop up?

Comment: This question is far too broad. Integer conversions depend both on the operands and the operators present in the operation. In order to properly answer this, the answer would have to address integer types (C11 6.2.6.2), integer promotion (C11 6.3.1.1), signed/unsigned conversion (C11 6.3.1.3), the usual arithmetic conversions (C11 6.3.1.8), assignment (C11 6.5.16.1)... and so on.

Comment: And how do I know how broad is subject when I don't know how broad that subject is? Thank you for provided standard reading, though.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

An integral conversion never produces undefined behaviour (it can produce implementation-defined behaviour).

A conversion to a type that can represent the value being converted is always well-defined: the value simply stays unchanged.

A conversion to an unsigned type is always well-defined: the value is taken modulo UINT_MAX+1 (or whatever maximum value the target type admits).

A conversion to a signed type that cannot represent the value being converted results in either an implementation-defined value, or an implementation-defined signal.

Note that the above rules are defined in terms of integer values and not in terms of sequences of bits.

Comment: So conversion from any type(signed/unsigned/bigger/smaller) to unsigned is always defined as `value%(maximum for type being converted to +1)` ?

Comment: This answer would be improved by changing “UB” to “undefined behavior” and by changing “modulo UINT_MAX+1 (or whatever maximum value the target type admits)“ to “modulo one more than the maximum value of the target type (e.g., 65536 for a 16-bit unsigned short in which the maximum value is 65535)”. (This proposed new wording is still cumbersome, but I strongly suggest avoiding `UINT_MAX` since that is a specific value for `unsigned int`, but this statement is for other types as well.)

Comment: And isn't that expression equivalent to my truncating/preppending with 0's but more formal way?

Comment: @EricPostpischil: I in fact have tried to avoid too long-winded wording. Will think about it again...

Comment: @zubergu: it probably is equivalent, for unsigned types. Note that the standard does not even require binary representation of signed types, so you cannot even portably talk about their bits.

Comment: @n.m.: What do you mean the standard doesn't require binary representation of signed types? Value bits correspond to their counterparts in the unsigned type, there is exactly a sign bit that either negates the value or has a value of -(2^M) or -(2^(M)-1), and there may be padding bits. How is that not a binary representation? (Of course, the OP's sign-extension doesn't work for sign-magnitude representation)

Comment: @ninjalj You are right, C99 requires binary representation. C89 AFAIK did not.

Answer (score 1):

From C standard document (p.50 draft version 201x I believe and not exact quote):

- No two signed integer shall have the same rank
- The rank of signed integer shall be greater than the rank of any signed integer with less precision.
- long long int is greater than long int which is greater than int which is greater than short int which is greater than signed char.
- signed and unsigned of same precision have same rank (ex: signed int is same rank as unsigned int)
- The rank of any standard integer type shall be greater than the rank of any extended integer type of same width.
- The rank of char is equal to unsigned char is equal to signed char.

(I'm leaving out bool because you excluded them from your question)

- The rank of any extended signed integer relative to another extended signed integer is implementation-defined but still subject to other rules of integer conversion rank.
- for all integer types T1 T2 and T3, is T1 has greater rank than T2 and T2 has greater rank than T3, than T1 has greater rank than T3.

An object with an integer type (other than int and signed int) whose integer rank is LESS than or EQUAL to the rank of int and unsigned int, a bit field of type _Bool, int, signed int or unsigned int; if an int can represent all values of the original type, the value is converted to an int. Otherwise to an unsigned int. All other types are changed by the integer promotion.

In plain terms:

Any type "smaller" than int or unsigned int get promoted to int when converted to other type of greater rank. This is the compiler's job to ensure that a C code compiled for a given machine (architecture) is ISO-C compliant in that regard. char is implementation defined (being signed or unsigned). All other types (promotion or "demotion") are implementation-defined.

What is implementation-defined? It means that a given compiler will systematically behave the same on a given machine. In other words all "implementation-defined" behavior depends BOTH on the compiler AND the target machine.

To make portable code:

- always promote values to greater rank standard C types.
- Never "demote" values to lesser types.
- Avoid all "implementation-defined" implementation in your code.

Why that implementation-defined madness exists if it ruins programmers' effort??? System programming basically requires these implementation-defined behavior.

So more specifically toward your question:

- truncation will most likely not be protable. Or will require much more effort in maintenance, bug tracking etc, than simply maintaining the code by using higher rank types.
- If your implementation runs values bigger than the types involved, your design is wrong (unless you are involved in system programming).
- As a rule of thumb, going from unsigned to signed preserves values but not the other way around. So when an unsigned value goes toe to toe against a signed one, promote the unsigned to signed instead of the other way around.
- If using as small integer types as possible is memory-critical in your application, you should probably revisit the whole program's achitecture.

Comment: There are two types of implicit integer conversions: the integer promotions which you describe here, and balancing ("the usual arithmetic conversions"), which you don't mention at all.

Comment: I just re-checked the standard and my understanding is that the above rules do cover both cases. However, in the type definition section (that appears a bit before this one), there are some rules about signed vs unsigned but the scope is larger than just integers and do not invalidate the rule of thumbs above. If I'm missing a section from the standard, I'll be happy to review my answer accordingly.

Comment: No, you left out balancing entirely. Integer promotion that you describe takes place before balancing. For example if you have an operation where the parameters are `(char) + (long)`, integer promotion first promotes the char, giving `(int) + (long)`. Balancing then promotes the int to long, the calculation will be done on types `(long) + (long)`. See the standard 6.3.1.8.

Comment: 6.3.1.8 concerns double. The integer section is the one I quoted and applies both the simple affectation (ex: an int a = b where be is a char) and to any arithmetic operation. Notice the wording is operation agnostic and operation precedence takes place. The example you give is covered by my text above. I stand by my other comment above...