# Array indexing and usual arithmetic conversion

Tags: c, integer, type-conversion, implicit-conversion

In C, when I use an integer as an array index, does this trigger usual arithmetic conversion rules to convert the array index to some integer type? If so, which integer type does it get converted to?

Example 1:

```
int i = ...;
... a[i] ...
```

Does this trigger an integer conversion or promotion?  If so, what type is `i` converted to?  (`unsigned int`?  `size_t`?  something else?)

Example 2:

```
unsigned int j = ...;
... b[j] ...
```

Does this trigger an integer conversion or promotion?  If so, what type is `i` converted to?

What if the type of the index is something other than `int`?  What are the rules for when it undergoes integer conversion?  Are the usual arithmetic conversion rules applied, or something?

I am also interested in the same question about pointer arithmetic, e.g., the expression `p+i` where `p` is a pointer and `i` is some integral type.

I've looked at the [CERT Secure Coding guidelines on understanding integer conversions](https://www.securecoding.cert.org/confluence/display/seccode/INT02-C.+Understand+integer+conversion+rules) and the [OWASP overview of integer overflow](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Integer_overflow), but neither resource describes this case.  Neither does the following StackOverflow question: [Integer conversions(narrowing, widening), undefined behaviour](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19273658/781723).

Comment: Usual conversions mean the target type is `int`...unless it's too big to fit in which case it goes to `unsigned int`, `long`, `unsigned long`... etc

Comment: @JonathanLeffler, yeah, I'm familiar with the usual conversions.  My question: do they apply here, and how?  Are usual conversions applied to convert the array index to `int`, or to some other type -- and if so, to which type? What are the rules that govern this situation?  I can find documentation of what the usual arithmetic conversions are, but they seem to assume I already know what the target type should be, and I can't tell how to know what the target type of an array index should be.

Comment: C99 §6.5.2.1 makes no claim that the type is `int`, only that it is an integer-type.  "One of the expressions shall have type ‘‘pointer to complete object type’’, the other expression shall have **integer type**, and the result has type "type".

Comment: The index expression will be subject to 'usual conversions' and then used as is (well scaled by the size of the type of the array elements).  There isn't anything much more to be said, I think.  Negative offsets can be used and may even be valid if the indexed pointer is known to point part way through an array.  In your example 1, the type of the subscript is `int`; there's no further conversion. In your example 2, the type of the subscript is `unsigned int`; there's no further conversion.  You can't use a floating point number as an index.  You can't use a pointer as index (ignoring `i[a]`).

Comment: Cool, many thanks @WhozCraig!  So how does that apply here?  What are the implications for the question I asked in the body of the question?  Should I infer if the index is already an integer-type, then no promotions or conversions are applied?  Thanks again!

Comment: @JonathanLeffler, cool, thank you.  Would you like to convert that into an answer so I can upvote/accept it?  (There is one remaining case: what if the type of `i` is something larger than `int`: `long`, `size_t`, `unsigned long`, etc.  But that's less important to me.)

Comment: Jonathan summed it up nicely. Promotions, if any, are used in the expression itself, but one way or another it has to be integer-type when finished. I.e. You can't use `ar[1.01]` and expect a promotion from `double` to `int` to happen because it is used as an subscript index; it won't. But you *can* do `ar[x+y*z]` and so long as `x+y*z`, when finished doing its do-I-need-to-convert-to-fulfill-this-expression thing is done, results in an integer-type, its ok. I can't describe it better than that. (at least as i read it).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Section 6.5.2.1, paragraph 2 of [C99](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/WG14/www/docs/n1256.pdf) says:

> ... The definition of the subscript operator [] is that E1[E2] is
>   identical to (*((E1)+(E2)))...

Which implies rules for the + apply:

> For addition, either both operands shall have arithmetic type, or one
>   operand shall be a pointer to an object type and the other shall have
>   integer type. (Incrementing is equivalent to adding 1.)

So, when first argument for + is a pointer the second must have an integer type and no conversion is being made.

Note:

E2 in the frist quote is expression, and as such can contain many type conversion as it's computed. The important thing is that the resulting type is an integer type.