# Converting non existing ASCII char to int in C

Tags: c, type-conversion

```
int i = 65537;
char c = (char) i;
printf("%d", c);
```

I'm getting "1" from that and I'm wondering why

Comment: `65537 % 256 = ????` ;)

Comment: you are going to print first byte of integer and it depends on your machine(read from MSB or LSB)

Comment: "65537 % 256 = ????"
what does that mean?

Answer (score 0):

`i` is defined `int` (32 bits) the value in binary is `65537 = 10000000000000001`
when `c = (char)` i the value is truncated because c is in 8 bits so 
c will be `c = 00000001` so c = 1

Comment: That is just one way of implementing it. The result may be different.

Answer (score -1):

Mostly int has 32 bits, while char has only 8 bits. If you cast int to char, you throw away the remaining 24 bits. The result is not defined.

Comment: The result is defined, implementation-defined.

Comment: Nope, you are wrong, what if you change the constant? We might get negative sign as well. I said it is undefined because the output does not relate anything to input. But you can calculate it.

Comment: In addition, don't forget endian byte order. You don't know which platforms you are running. Big-endian and little-endian will result in different answers.

Comment: Conversion of any integer type to a signed type is implementation-defined. Standard doesn't define endianness and it isn't relevant for here. Please see the current standard at heading: 6.3.1.3 §3

Comment: Please read my comments throughly. I said the result is not defined. I'm talking about the result only. Standard is irrelevant. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19273658/integer-conversionsnarrowing-widening-undefined-behaviour