# Access violation error - ucrtbased.dll

Tags: c++, access-violation

> Exception thrown at 0x0F4CD6F0 (ucrtbased.dll) in ChatClient.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000068.

I've been struggling to find the source of this error for days and I've finally isolated a snippet to illustrate the problem I'm having. The exception is thrown immediately after the switch statement. I have no idea what is causing this "access violation" in this relatively mundane piece of code you can see below:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <conio.h>

int main(){
    bool room = true, type = true;
    string input;
    unsigned int scroll = 0;
    while (room) {
        cout << input;
        /* Input */
        int ch = _getch();
        switch (ch) {
        case 72: /* scroll up */
            if (!type && scroll != sizeof(unsigned int))
                scroll++;
            break;
        case 80: /* scroll down */
            if (!type && scroll != 0)
                scroll--;
            break;
        case 13: /* Send message */
            input.clear();
            scroll = 0;
            break;
        case 27: // Quit loop
            room = false;
            break;
        case 9: // Switch between scrolling and typing modes
            if (type)
                type = false;
            else
                type = true;
            break;
        default:
            if (type && ch != -32) {
                input.append((char*)ch);
            }
            break;
        }
    } <- Exception thrown, probably when the while loop condition is re-evaluated?
    return 0;
}
```

Using Visual Studio 2017 with the default IDE debug tools.

Comment: _"I've been struggling to find the source of this error for days"_ Did any of that struggle include using a debugger? `input.append((char*)ch);` ...what? Why are you casting to a pointer? `string` will then try to read that memory address... What you want is to append an ASCII `char`, not a `char*` at the corresponding memory address. I'm therefore voting to close this as being caused by a simple typographic error.

Comment: Please avoid the use of [*magic numbers*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming)). If by e.g. `13` you mean the [ASCII](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ascii) carriage-return character `'\r'` then *say* so by using the actual character.

Comment: I used "magic numbers" because _getch return type int. I will be more careful in the future.

Comment: `input.append((char*)ch);` is a bad idea ;)

Comment: Doesn't matter. Using ASCII then `'\r' == 13`.

Comment: @Lolechi C++ will do the implicit conversion for you; if you really want to be certain you can use `(int)'\r'`. But _please_ be explicit!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
input.append((char*)ch);
```

Why are you casting to a pointer? That is extremely wrong. Due to function overload resolution, `std::string` will try to read a C string starting at the memory address corresponding to the cast ASCII value of that character... which is not your memory to use. Hence an access violation... at best.

What you want is to append an ASCII `char`, not a `char*` at the corresponding memory address.

While you're at it, use the proper C++ cast, which would have errored-out on this one and never let you compile it. Then again, if you had any warnings on, even the old C cast should've at least warned about this.

```
input.append( static_cast<char>(ch) );
```

(N.B.: I assume `getch()` doesn't return any `int` that cannot be safely casted to `char` in your case. I didn't look into its docs as it seems to be some old `conio` silliness. If the value might be out of range, it's your responsibility to check that, as casting while causing overflow invokes <s>undefined</s> [unreliable/non-portable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19273658/integer-conversionsnarrowing-widening-undefined-behaviour) behaviour at best.)