downcasting a double/float to a uint8_t
Let's say I have the following bit of code, which tries to 'downcast' a double value into a uint8_t:
uint8_t downcast(uint8_t *down1, uint8_t *down2)
{
    //the usual nullptr checks
    double fval = 100.0; //fits the uint8_t domain range
    *down1 = (uint8_t)fval;  //should work...

    fval = 1000.0; //does not fit uint8_t domain range
    *down2 = (uint8_t)fval;  //will this work??
}

I've seen a few posts that suggest doing this sort of "quantization-cast", but I'm not sure this is correct.  I seem to recall reading that a double var whose value exceeds the output domain, will lead to undefined behavior from the cast (either C or static_cast<uint8_t>(fval)).
Thoughts?

The behaviour of the second cast is undefined.

C17 §6.3.1.4 ¶1 When a finite value of real floating type is converted to an integer type other than _Bool, the fractional part is discarded (i.e., the value is truncated toward zero). If the value of the integral part cannot be represented by the integer type, the behavior is undefined.


Thanks!  I did find this SO explanation about this part of the standard.  The examples herein nicely explain my situation, which is similar.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75578931/how-to-intrepret-paragraph-1-of-section-6-3-1-4-of-c11-standard-about-convertin
