# Printing the hex value stored as a string gives unexpected output

Tags: c, string, char, hex, printf

I have in C language hex numbers defined in string:

```
char chars[] = "\xfb\x54\x9c\xb2\x10\xef\x89\x51\x2f\x0b\xea\xbb\x1d\xaf\xad\xf8";
```

Then I want to compare the values with another. It is not working and if I print the value like:

```
printf("%02x\n", chars[0]);
```

it writes `fffffffb`. Why is that and how to get `fb` value exactly?

Comment: When working with binary data you always want to use `unsigned char`. I would change the declaration rather than adding casts.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is because of the sign extension.

Change

```
printf("%02x\n", chars[0]);
```

to

```
printf("%02x\n", (unsigned char)chars[0]);
```

The `%x` format specifier will read `4 bytes` on 32bit machine. As you have declared `chars`  as the character array, when fetching the value `fb`(negative value) will be sign extended as `fffffffb`, where the MSB of `fb` is set to all other bits before it.

Refer this for more details [sign extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19260052/sign-extension-in-c)

If you would have declared `char chars[]` as `unsigned char chars[]` then the print would have been as expected.

Answer (score 2):

As per the standard mentioning regarding the `%x` format specifier with `fprintf()`

> `o,u,x,X`
>
> The unsigned int argument is converted to unsigned octal (**o**), unsigned
>   decimal (**u**), or **unsigned hexadecimal notation (x or X)** in the style *dddd*; [...]

So, the expected type of argument to `%x` is `unsigned int`.

Now, `printf()` being a variadic function, only default promotion rule is applied to its arguments. In your code, `chars` being an array of type `char` (signedness of which is implementation dependent), in case of

```
printf("%02x\n", chars[0]);
```

the value of `chars[0]` get promoted to an `int` which is not the expected type for `%x`. Hence, the output is wrong, as `int` and `unsigned int` are not the same type. [Refer §6.7.2, `C11`]. So, without an explicit cast like

```
printf("%02x\n", (unsigned int)chars[0]);
```

it invokes [undefined behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

FWIW, if you're having a C99 supported compiler, you can make use of the `hh`  length modifier to work around this, like

```
 printf("%02hhx\n", (unsigned char)chars[0]);
```

Comment: [Minor sidenote]: I think, that there is a common consensus betwwen C developers, that `%x` format specifier is valid for `int` object, that holds _nonnegative_ value. For instance `{ int i = 100; printf("%x\n", i); }` is acceptable, even if type is not `unsigned int`. But, strictly speaking it is UB, right?

Comment: @GrzegorzSzpetkowski Yes, that is what I know. :-)

Answer (score 0):

It's because of sign extension.

This will work as you expect:

```
printf("%02x\n", (unsigned char)chars[0]);
```